# Add styles to button when is active and remove them when clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, draftjs

Im working with react and Draft.js in a plataform with meetings, forums, etc. This editor allows the user to take notes during the meetings. What i want to achieve is that when the user clicks 'Italic' add the .active class to let know the user that the button is active (change the background color) And remove it when is not. This is my code:

```
export const ActionButton = styled.div`
  color: #272a2d;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  margin-top: 13px;

 .active {
   background-color: pink
 }

&:hover {
  background-color: #f2f4f6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.icon-toolbar-custom-icons {
border: none;
border-radius: 8px;
padding: 5px;

&:hover {
  background-color: #f2f4f6;
}

${mediaQuery} {
  padding: 0;
}
}
`;
const estilosTooltipInfo = makeStyles(theme => ({
arrow: {
 color: theme.palette.common.black,
 },
tooltip: {
 backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
 fontSize: '13px',
 padding: '8px 10px',
 borderRadius: 6,
 },
}));
 function TooltipInfo(props) {
  const classes = estilosTooltipInfo();
  return <Tooltip placement="bottom" classes={classes} {...props} />;
 }

function TooltipItalic(props) {
const handleSetItalic = () => {
const newState = RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(props.editorState, 'ITALIC');
if (newState) {
  props.onChange(newState);
}
   };
 return (
<div>
  <TooltipInfo title="Cursiva">
    <ActionButton
      className="icon-toolbar-custom-icons"
      onClick={handleSetItalic}
    >
      <FormatItalicIcon />
    </ActionButton>
  </TooltipInfo>
</div>
 );
}
```

i don't know how to achieve this in my onClick method. I know it should be easy but i'm having a hard time here.

Comment: use `onMouseDown` instead of `onclick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy. What you need is [getCurrentLinlineStyle](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state/#getcurrentinlinestyle) of EditorState. It holds current (that you've selected) inline styles. You could see the link with the example below.

[Codesanbox example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/atomic-ci3h9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

use onMouseDown instead of onclick event will do that,

```
export default function MyEditor() {
  
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(
    () => EditorState.createEmpty(),
  );    
  

  const _onBoldClick = () => {
        setEditorState(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(editorState, 'BOLD'))
  }  

  return(
    <div>
        <button 
        // onClick={_onBoldClick} 
        onMouseDown={e=> {
          e.preventDefault();
          setEditorState(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(editorState, 'BOLD'))
        }}>BOLD</button>
        <div
        >
          <Editor 
            textAlignment="left" placeholder="Enter something here" 
            editorState={editorState} onChange={setEditorState} />
        </div>
        
    </div>
  ) 
  
    
}
```